# Error in Gamma Ray data: chi square value

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, error, poisson-regression, error-propagation

I have Gamma-ray data for which I am fitting the stars with a constant (one parameter) first to remove the unwanted or garbage data. I plotted counts vs MJD value. For this data as Poisson, the error is the $\sqrt{counts}$ used as error bars.

I also added a 2nd panel below i.e $\frac{(model value−data value)^2}{(error)^2}$ on the y-axis and MJD values as x-axis where the error is the data $\sqrt{value}$ as per Poisson statistics. I want to fit each point with error bars so I want to evaluate error for each point in this second panel. This way I can look for models and trends in the data (if present).

So for example,in the figure attached, in the 3rd point, I have model value ≈140, and data value ≈190, $(difference)^2=50^2=2500$, what would be the error for such a data and the error for the $\chi$-square value which I plotted?  Moreover, what should be the value of the corresponding point in the lower panel?

[image: fitted plots]

Comment: Can you explain MJD and please, some more context?

Comment: MJD is nothing but modified Julian dates, obtained by subtracting 2,400,000.5 days from the Julian date JD, The MJD, therefore, gives the number of days since midnight on November 17, 1858